# LINENO and BASH_LINENO

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

So I'm not sure why this is..  I know ${LINENO} normally contains the line in the script, and BASH_LINENO goes based on input from BASH_SOURCE as an array

```
$ (echo hi;declare -p LINENO BASH_LINENO;echo -e "My LINENO\tis\t${LINENO}\nMy BASH_LINENO\tis\t${BASH_LINENO[@]}")
hi
declare -- LINENO="34"
declare -a BASH_LINENO=()
My LINENO   is  34
My BASH_LINENO  is
```

But why when I am working interactively is LINENO coming back as 30+ then incrementing every time I run echo (note like when I am saying interactive I am meaning like this is an activate shell with pty attached and fd 0, 1, and 2 being there).  Can anyone explain to me why LINENO is at 33, 34, 35 etc when running multiple times?

Comment: start a new shell, run `echo $LINENO`, it shows 1 since that's the first input line. Run it again, it shows 2 since that's the second input line, etc.

Comment: Aha, thanks yeah that was it, this could be useful for history expansion if stored PROMPT_COMMAND or PS1 to help  you count backwards for history expansion...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says (bold mine):

> LINENO
>
>   Each time this parameter is referenced, the shell substitutes a
>   decimal number representing the current sequential line number
>   (starting with 1) within a script or function.
>   **When not in a script
>   or function,  the value substituted is not guaranteed to be
>   meaningful.**
>   If LINENO is unset, it loses its special properties,
>   even if it is subsequently reset.